# Always shows 404 error page with spring

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to fetch data from Spring mvc jdbc template and display in table format .But always the 404 error comes up.

```
    package com.sample.complaint.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.sample.domain.TrackComplaints;
import com.sample.services.TrackComplaintsService;

@Controller
public class TrackComplaintsController {

    @Autowired
    ComplaintsService complaintservice;


    @RequestMapping("/userList" )
    public ModelAndView Complaints() {

        List<Complaints> complaintlist = complaintservice.getComplaintsList();

        return new ModelAndView("userList", "Complaints",
                complaintlist);
    }
}
```

My ApplicationContect.xml //dispatcher servlet

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />


 <!-- telling container to take care of annotations stuff -->
 <context:annotation-config />

 <!-- declaring base package -->
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.sample.*" />


 <!-- adding view resolver to show jsp's on browser -->
 <bean id="viewResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>

 <!-- declare beans -->
 <bean id="trackcomplainsdao" class="com.sample.dao.ComplaintsDaoImpl" />
 <bean id="trackcomplaintservice" class="com.sample.services.ComplaintsSerImpl" />

 <!-Datasource code is present--!>


</beans>
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
 <display-name>SpringJDBCTemplate</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>  
 </welcome-file-list>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>ApplicationContext</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ApplicationContext</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

userList.jsp

```
%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Complaint</title>

</head>
<body>
 <center> 
 <b>Complaints </b>
  <table border="1">
   <tr>
    <td class="heading">asd</td>
    <td class="heading">Sasde</td>
    <td class="heading">erte</td>
    <td class="heading">gjg</td>
    <td class="heading">Sghj</td>
    <td class="heading">vbn</td>
    <td class="heading">vbngh</td>
    <td class="heading">gfh</td>
   </tr>
   <c:forEach var="complaints" items="${complaintsList}">
    <tr>
     <td>${complaints.asd}</td>
     <td>${complaints.Sasde}</td>
     <td>${complaints.erte}</td>
     <td>${complaints.gjg}</td>
     <td>${complaints.Sghj}</td>
    <td>${complaints.vbn}</td>
    <td>${complaints.vbngh}</td>
    <td>${complaints.gfh}</td>>    
    </tr>
   </c:forEach>

  </table>
 </center>
</body>
</html>
```

I dont know whether i am missing the request mapping or something else.thank in advance

console:

```
Sep 24, 2014 5:44:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;D:\oracle\TCSHYDISUSER\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN;C:\OraHome_1\bin;C:\OraHome_1;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;;C:\Java IDE\eclipse-jee-kepler-R-win32\eclipse;;.
    Sep 24, 2014 5:44:37 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:sample' did not find a matching property.
    Sep 24, 2014 5:44:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Sep 24, 2014 5:44:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Sep 24, 2014 5:44:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 418 ms
    Sep 24, 2014 5:44:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    Sep 24, 2014 5:44:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
    Sep 24, 2014 5:44:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
    Sep 24, 2014 5:44:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'ApplicationContext'
    Sep 24, 2014 5:44:41 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
    INFO: FrameworkServlet 'ApplicationContext': initialization started
    Sep 24, 2014 5:44:41 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
    INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'ApplicationContext-servlet': startup date [Wed Sep 24 17:44:41 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    Sep 24, 2014 5:44:42 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
    INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/ApplicationContext-servlet.xml]
    Sep 24, 2014 5:44:43 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
    INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@256b49: defining beans [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,trackComplaintsController,viewResolver,trackcomplainsdao,trackcomplaintservice,dataSource,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
    Sep 24, 2014 5:44:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
    INFO: Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler#0'
    Sep 24, 2014 5:44:43 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
    INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    Sep 24, 2014 5:44:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
    INFO: FrameworkServlet 'ApplicationContext': initialization completed in 1883 ms
    Sep 24, 2014 5:44:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Sep 24, 2014 5:44:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Sep 24, 2014 5:44:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 5693 ms
```

Comment: Does `/WEB-INF/jsp/userList.jsp` exist?  That's where you're forwarding with `new ModelAndView("userList", "Complaints",  complaintlist);`.

Comment: yes in the same path

Comment: Just checking, because the jsp you're showing us is called complaint.jsp.

Comment: sorry.. i made mess while pasting here its userList.jsp